# Composer, no "$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin" folder

Tags: php, composer-php

In a tutorial, after installing Composer like this :

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

It recommends to do this change to shell configuration,
so that Composer can install commands within the user account:

```
sed -i '1i export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' $HOME/.bashrc
```

But in my case, in `$HOME/.composer/` I DO NOT have a `vendor` folder. There's only a `.htaccess` file and a `cache` folder.

What's wrong?
Is it because of a new version of Composer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is when you **don't** have any packages installed globally (see [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global) for more info about global packages). These global packages are installed to `$HOME/.composer/vendor/` and some might have a binary which would install into `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin`.

To be able to run these binaries from any of your Composer projects it needs to be in your `PATH`:

```
sed -i '1i export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' $HOME/.bashrc
```

So nothing is wrong. Just add this folder to your `PATH`. It should be no problem if this folder doesn't exist yet. It will be automatically created as soon as you install a global package with binaries (see example below).

---

#### Example

An example for a package which is a good idea to install globally instead of your projects folder is [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de) (a PHP Testing Framework). You can install it with

```
composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=5.0.*"
```

If you have a look into your `$HOME/.composer/vendor/` you will recognize a `phpunit` folder and also a `bin` folder.